# Why is a span container box even smaller than its image child?

Tags: html, css, inline

Example: https://codepen.io/pen/MWJKxwX

Telling from the border, the span contains the image horizontally, but not vertically.

This inconsistency feels quite weird to me. Is it formally defined in the spec? What is the intuition behind this design?

```css
span {
  border: 1px solid;
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<span>hello world<img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png"></span>
```

Comment: add this on span `display:inline-block;`

Comment: @LaljiTadhani that does not change the appearance in my case. But I was not asking how to make the `span` large enough to contain the image anyway. I'm interested in why is it this way.